# How do I loop over a string and add words that start with a certain letter to an empty list?

Tags: python, loops, startswith

So for an assignment I have to create an empty list variable `empty_list = []`, then have python loop over a string, and have it add each word that starts with a `'t'` to that empty list. My attempt:

```
text = "this is a text sentence with words in it that start with letters"
empty_list = []
for twords in text:
    if text.startswith('t') == True:
        empty_list.append(twords)
    break
print(empty_list)
```

This just prints a single [t]. I'm pretty sure I'm not using `startswith()` correctly. How would I go about making this work correctly?

Comment: You need `for twords in text.split():`

Comment: What was your reasoning for adding the `break`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution for you. You also need to replace `text.startswith('t')` by `twords.startswith('t')` because you are now using `twords` to iterate through each word of your original statement stored in `text`. You used `break` which would only make your code print `this` since after finding the first word, it will break outside the for loop. To get all the words beginning with `t`, you need to get rid of the `break`.

```
text = "this is a text sentence with words in it that start with letters"
empty_list = []
for twords in text.split():
    if twords.startswith('t') == True:
        empty_list.append(twords)
print(empty_list)
> ['this', 'text', 'that']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "this is a text sentence with words in it that start with letters"
print([word for word in text.split() if word.startswith('t')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`text = "this is a text sentence with words in it that start with letters"
t = text.split(' ')
ls = [s for s in t if s.startswith('t')]`

`ls` will be the resulting list

Python is great for using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works,

```
empty_list = []
for i in text.split(" "):
if i.startswith("t"):
    empty_list.append(i)
print(empty_list)
```

The problem in your code is,

> You are iterating each letter, that's wrong